# Power BI embed with React Js

Tags: powerbi, embed

This is the first time I am trying to embed a Power BI report with React.

I used the following method and it is working fine. But the issue is that my access token failed after nearly one hour. When I run the project after one hour I have to generate a new access code and add it into the following code. What is the solution for this ?

my code -->

```
<PowerBIEmbed
            embedConfig={{
                type: 'report', 
                id: 'xxxxx',
                embedUrl: "xxxxx",
                accessToken: ' xxxxxxxxx',
                tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
                settings: {
                    panes: {
                        filters: {
                            expanded: false,
                            visible: false
                        }
                    },
                    background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
                }
            }}
            eventHandlers={
                new Map([
                    ['loaded', function () { console.log('Report loaded'); }],
                    ['rendered', function () { console.log('Report rendered'); }],
                    ['error', function (event) { console.log(event.detail); }]
                ])
            }

            cssClassName={"Embed-container"}

            getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
                window.report = embeddedReport;
            }}
        />
```

Thank you
Jeewan

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase a premium licence.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-features